# Persistent transient keymap for mouse scrolling

Tags: keymap

I'm trying to create a [transient keymap](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Controlling-Active-Maps.html) that calls calls `quick-peek-hide` on any key except mouse scrolling, which should function normally.

I've got the following:

```el
(let ((map (make-sparse-keymap))) 
  (define-key map [mouse-4] #'mwheel-scroll)
  (define-key map [mouse-5] #'mwheel-scroll) 
  (define-key map [t] #'quick-peek-hide)
  (set-transient-map map <keep-pred> <on-exit>))
```

And don't know what should be the values of `<keep-pred>` and `<on-exit>` should be.

If `keep-pred` is `t`, wouldn't the transient map remain active forever because we define the default key `[t]`? If `on-exit` is `#'quick-peek-hide`, scrolling would invoke `quick-peek-hide` instead of simply doing `mwheel-scroll`.

**Update:**

A few observations:

- The default keybinding `[t]` does *not* keep the transient map active.

```el
(let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
  (define-key map [t] (lambda ()
                        (interactive)
                        (message "default!"))) 
  (set-transient-map map t))
```

Activating the above transient map causes the next key to message `default!`, but exits the transient map thereafter.

- Mouse events are preceded by `down-` mouse events, so it is *not* sufficient to bind `[mouse-4]`, `[mouse-5]`, etc.

For example, `describe-key` for a mouse scroll down gives:

> `<mouse-5>` (translated from `<down-mouse-5> <mouse-5>`) at that spot runs the command `mwheel-scroll`

So scrolling down with the following:

```el
(let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
  (dolist (scroll-key (where-is-internal #'mwheel-scroll))
    (define-key map scroll-key (lambda ()
                                 (interactive)
                                 (message "scroll-key!")))) 
  (define-key map [t] (lambda ()
                        (interactive)
                        (message "default!"))) 
  (set-transient-map map t))
```

Does *not* message `scroll-key!`, but `default!`.

- Hacking the following together:

```el
(let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
  (dolist (scroll-key (where-is-internal #'mwheel-scroll))
    (define-key map scroll-key (lambda ()
                                 (interactive)
                                 (message "scroll-key!")))) 
  (define-key map [t] (lambda ()
                        (interactive)
                        (message "default!")))

  (define-key map (kbd "<down-mouse-5>") (lambda ()
                                           (interactive)
                                           (message "down-mouse-5!"))) 
  (set-transient-map map t))
```

The *first* scroll down message `down-mouse-5!` and `scroll-key!`, but the next one messages `default` and exits the transient map.

So the question is: **what keys/events need to be bound to prevent scrolling from exiting the transient map?**.

Comment: `set-transient-map` was invented specifically to avoid the need to use `[t]` bindings (since these are always problematic: they prevent `input-decode-map` and friends from doing their job and there is no 100% reliable way to *unread* an event).

Comment: The `[t]` bindings allow a keypress to `quick-peek-hide`, but not the execute the key's usual function. I want every key (except scrolling) after `quick-peek-show` to `quick-peek-hide`, not do what they'd normally do (insert char, etc.). Is there a way to achieve that *without* binding `[t]`?

Comment: You can use the `on-exit` argument where you can set `this-command` to `ignore` in order to cause the exiting key to "do nothing".

Comment: Hmm, ok. That actually seems *less* straightforward than binding `[t]`. Is the issue w/ binding `[t]` that the specific key is not recorded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I think I've got it!

**@compunaut** [set me on the right track](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/32828/10269). No need to screw with bindings; `KEEP-PRED` and `ON-EXIT` are enough.

```el
(set-transient-map map
                   (lambda ()
                     (eq #'mwheel-scroll this-command))
                   (lambda ()
                     (quick-peek-hide)
                     (setq this-command #'ignore)))
```

The trick is to deal with *commands* rather than *events*, because it's hard to figure out which sequences of events are translated into which commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a function as the `KEEP-PRED` argument. If it returns non-nil the map stays active. With the following only `C-g` will exit the `map`.

```el
(let ((map (make-sparse-keymap))) 
  (define-key map [mouse-4] 'mwheel-scroll)
  (define-key map [mouse-5] 'mwheel-scroll)
  (define-key map (kbd "C-g") 'ignore) 
  (define-key map [t] (lambda ()
                        (interactive)
                        (message "Don't leave that map!!!")))
  (set-transient-map map (lambda ()
                           (not (equal (this-command-keys) (kbd "C-g"))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

> If `keep-pred` is `t`, wouldn't the transient map remain active forever because we define the default key `[t]`?

Perhaps. It might be a special case. Seems simple enough to test, but in any case, `keep-pred` can be a custom function, so you can always use that facility. I'd guess you'd be checking `last-command-event` against the anticipated values.

> If `on-exit` is `#'quick-peek-hide`, scrolling would invoke `quick-peek-hide` instead of simply doing `mwheel-scroll`.

Why would you set that value? Your default key binding already takes care of calling `quick-peek-hide` for the situations you want it to be called in.

Answer (score 0):

My crystal ball is pretty clouded but I get the impression it wants to tell me that you should print the "current event" (i.e. `(this-command-keys`) when you exit the transient-map, and that will help you figure out which bindings are missing.